# How to correctly solve a linear nonhomogeneouous first order equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am studying Trench, Elementary Diffeq with Boundary Value Problems, chapter 4.2 Mixing Problems

I have the differential equation $Q'+\frac{1}{(t+100)}Q=1$,
The solution of the complementary equation is $Q = \frac{1}{(t+100)}$
The solution of the linear nonhomogeneouous first order equation is $Q=\frac{u}{(t+100)}$ where $u'/(t+100)=1$, so $u'=t+100$.
Integrating, we find $u=\frac{(t+100^2)}{2} + c$ . 
This is the correct answer but what if I do the following:

$u = \displaystyle\int(t+100)dt$ 
  = $\displaystyle\int t dt + \displaystyle\int 100 dt?$

I get $\frac{t^2}{2} + \frac{200 t}{2} + c$

This is different from the first solution. 
Identities used are as follows:
$v=t+100, dv=dt$
$t = v-100$. 
I used $v$ to distinguish it from $u$

Why is the second approach not giving me the same answer?

MM

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please refer to [this guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in future when formatting questions/ answers.

Comment: Isn't $$Q'+\frac{1}{(t+100)}Q=1$$?

Comment: Yes. thank you. MM

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the first answer was $\frac{(t+100)^2}{2}+c$, the second answer is also a valid antiderivative. Because the $c$ on these tho different equations are independent/arbitrary. If I choose the second $c_2$ as $c_1+\frac{10000}{2}$ the equations become equal.

---

Edit:

Let's clarify this.

Both
$$F_1(t) = \dfrac{(t+100)^2}{2}+c$$
and
$$F_2(t) = \dfrac{t^2}{2} + \dfrac{200 t}{2} + c$$
are correct *antiderivatives* of $f(t) = t+100$. This means that,
$$\frac{d\,F_1(t)}{dt} = \frac{d\,F_2(t)}{dt} = f(t)$$
$$t+100 = t+100 = t+100$$
which is correct.

On the other hand, when you want to use an integral, you usually put values, or, limits, to the integral and make it a definite integral. This is acheived by using the [fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus):
$$\int\limits_{t=t_0}^{t_1}\,f(t)\,dt = F(t_1) - F(t_2)$$
where $F(t)$ is *any* antiderivative of $f(t)$.

Now, if we compare our two solutions in this manner,
$$\int\limits_{t=t_0}^{t_1}\,(t+100)\,dt =: I$$
$$I_1 := F_1(t_2) - F_1(t_1) = \left(\dfrac{(t_2+100)^2}{2}+c\right) - \left(\dfrac{(t_1+100)^2}{2}+c\right) $$
$$ = \dfrac{(t_2+100)^2}{2} - \dfrac{(t_1+100)^2}{2}$$
$$I_2 := F_2(t_2) - F_2(t_1) = \left(\dfrac{t_2^2}{2} + \dfrac{200 t_2}{2} + c\right) - \left(\dfrac{t_1^2}{2} + \dfrac{200 t_1}{2} + c\right)$$
$$ = \dfrac{t_2^2}{2} + \dfrac{200 t_2}{2} - \dfrac{t_1^2}{2} - \dfrac{200 t_1}{2}$$

As you can see, $I_1 = I_2$. But what does this mean? This means that using any antiderivative of choice does not change anything in the actual numeric results. You can add or subtract constants to an antiderivative and it still would be valid.

Comment: So if I were on a space ship and I wanted to be very precise would it make a difference which I used?

Comment: Nope. They are equivalent. I believe the confusion is because you are not putting the limits in yet. When you are taking a definite integral, both answers will give the same correct result.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: @MaryA.Marion I added some more explanation on how numeric results are found. It's more detailed this time.

Comment: Thank you. I am keeping this close at hand. It does clarify. I guess I will be more comfortable about that space ship now.